# How to paste from system clipboard content to an arbitrary window using Java

Tags: java, clipboard

I would like to write a Java program that has a button. When the button is pressed it pastes / drops the content of the system clipboard to the text field that currently has focus within an arbitrary, possibly non-Java app (say MS Word). Essentially the button action has to simulate the sending of CTRL-V (paste) action somehow.

Does any one have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The package `java.awt.datatransfer` seems to be a solution, [according to this article](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=39779). Here is [another article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82).

From the latter page, the needed imports:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
```

And the method code is below. The solution is to create a listener and add it to the button. The listener should simply get the contents of the clipboard and insert it to whatever component you wish.

```
public void setClipboardContents( String aString ){
  StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection( aString );
  Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
  clipboard.setContents( stringSelection, this );
}

public String getClipboardContents() {
  String result = "";
  Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
  //odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
  Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
  boolean hasTransferableText =
    (contents != null) &&
    contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)
  ;
  if ( hasTransferableText ) {
    try {
      result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ex){
      //highly unlikely since we are using a standard DataFlavor
      System.out.println(ex);
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Actions provided by the editor kits:

```
JButton paste = new JButton( new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction() );
```