# How to paste from system clipboard content to an arbitrary window using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard

I have the same question with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376975/how-to-paste-from-system-clipboard-content-to-an-arbitrary-window-using-java) but in Qt.

How to paste clipboard content to arbitrary locations ***** (simulate CTRL+V) in Qt?

***** paste the clipboard outside of your Qt application without pressing CTRL+V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're gonna have to resort to platform specifics for this.

First, you will somehow have to get the id/handle of the previously active application. In Windows, this can be done with  [`GetWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), as outlined [here](http://www.whitebyte.info/programming/how-to-get-main-window-handle-of-the-last-active-window). IN EWMH window managers, you can use the [_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2449346) property.

Second, you'll have to ask that window to perform a paste action. Again, in Windows, `SendMessage(window, WM_PASTE, 0, 0)` (docs for [[SendMessage]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WM_PASTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I'm actually not sure how you would accomplish this in X11.

There are problaby about 70 000 cases where the above approach won't work, but perhaps it can get you started?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [QClipboard](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qclipboard.html) class.

But I'm not sure to understand the question. What does "arbitrary location" means? Do you want to paste the clipboard outside of your Qt application? (I don't think that X11 and [ICCCM](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) and 
[EWMH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints) enables that).

Comment: QClipboard class has no functionality like this, it only gives you clipboard content and lets you manipulate it, thats all. What I want is to triger CTRL+V behavior without really pressing the key combination.